# NoSuchFieldError: id_tc26_signwithdigest_gost_3410_12_256

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Have anyone experience this error?

```
NoSuchFieldError: id_tc26_signwithdigest_gost_3410_12_256
```

What could be missing here?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
aused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id_tc26_signwithdigest_gost_3410_12_256
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.shredzone.acme4j.util.CSRBuilder.sign(CSRBuilder.java:265)
```

Comment: "Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed." Somehow you are modifying classes after they are loaded.

Comment: Most likely multiple versions of the BC jars on the classpath.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeah I found the problem wrong jars because of two BC-based acme library I was using

Comment: @PeterDettman indeed